# Humping pumping

Tags: idioms

I was watching the movie "When Harry Met Sally" and I had a trouble to understand this highlighted part of their conversation.

> Harry: No you didn't. A Sheldon can do your income taxes. If you need a root canal Sheldon's your man, but
>   ***humping and pumping***
>    is not Sheldon's strong suit. It's the name. Do it to me 'Sheldon', you're an animal 'Sheldon', ride me big 'Sheldon'. Doesn't work.

Comment: It's a sexual innuendo, that's all. It's referring to engaging in sex.

Answer (score 3):

Humping is slang for sex (or similar activities).

The phrase "humping and pumping" probably refers to an Arnold Swhwarzenegger quote:

> The best activities for your health are pumping and humping

When he said it, "pumping" referred to lifting weights.

It's not a common idiom but is easily understood.